# Better method to return Chunks of Data via jQuery, Ajax and ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have an ajax method that retrieves data based on criteria set on the page, this can be a few to alot of records.  I changed my ajax call to poll 25 records at a time instead of returning a large dataset.

The way I did this was on my WebMethod I run the sql based on the criteria and then I convert the rows to JSON and save to file on the first poll.  The subsequent ones simply load from the file back to classes so I can pick the next 25.  I need to run the data once on the first call and I can't simply pick 25 out because the function needs to load all records to perform other actions based on it.

My problem now is that a very large set of data was returned for one report which threw the error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

I already have the max set so it's clear I need to think of another way to save the firstly run data and send it back in chunks, any ideas please?

EDIT:
Essentially I'm looking for a way to save the class to file and retrieve it on subsequent requests.

Comment: look into asp.net caching

Comment: do you have any starter links as there's alot to look at.  Can you post it as an answer too

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the JSON to normal serialization like so:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("path/data" + model.reportId + ".txt"), FileMode.Create);
bf.Serialize(fileStream, preview);
fileStream.Close();
```

And to deserialize:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("path/data" + model.reportId + ".txt"), FileMode.Open);
fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
DataPreview savedPreview = (DataPreview)bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you have access to the all powerfull [`cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) object.

You can easily create your record set and then add it to the cache as follows:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("UniqueidentifierForObject", TheRecordSetObject, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, Nothing)
```

That will insert the object into the cache with an absolute expiration of 2 hours. If you look around there is a lot of good documentation about the cache so I am not going to go into great depth here. It is important to note how the cache is accessed also, because in a web method or service there is not going to be normal `httpContext` so you need to use the extended reference.

Then on subsequent calls for data you can get the object out of the cache by calling:

```
Dataset theDataset = HttpContext.Current.Cache("UniqueidentifierForObject");
if(theDataset == null){
    //CallYour load function because the cahce did not have your object
}else{
    //Do you pull for the chunk of data.
}
```

This way you only need to do your database call once but can get records from the set when ever you need.

Also it is important to note that ASP.NET is really good about serialization in web methods and services. [You don't normally have to serialize or deserialize data that is being passed from and too code behind in web methods and services](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/). It is usually done for you and trying to do it again could cause all kinds of strange behavior.